# Help me to install Antiqua Font

Tags: fonts, texmf

I was checking out [LaTeX Font Catalogue Antiqua](https://www.tug.org/FontCatalogue/antiqua/). It says that the package is not part of TeX Live.

So I went to [Antiqua on CTAN](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/psfonts/urwvf/), I downloaded the archive, extracted it and opened the README file.

And it says:

`move the three tfm directories from ./tfm/ to $TEXMF/fonts/tfm/urw/`

where on Windows `$TEXMF` is `C:\texlive\2020\texmf-dist`, right?

All right. The same with vf, afm, type1. Perfect.
The last passage is copying `./fontname/urw.map` and `./dvips/psfonts.map` to  their respective folders in `C:\texlive\2020\texmf-dist` in their respective folders, but I don't have these two folders. Do I have to create them?
I asked you because I don't want to mess with the installation.

Thank you very much.

Comment: better don't install anything into texmf-dist. Use texmf-local for your local additions. And yes, you can create missing folders, but better leave the map-files out, there are already in texlive.

Comment: Now I try and let you know

Comment: So I copied all the fonts and sty, but urw.map and psfonts. The console gave me an error. I tried to copy those two file (creating the folders). Again, error: name = uaqr8r, rootname = uaqr8r, pointsize = mktexmf: empty or non-existent rootfile!

Cannot find font uaqr8r in map file(s).


Il processo è terminato con uno o più errori

Comment: hm, i just checked, you are trying to install an outdated package. Why don't you use the antiqua which is in texlive? https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/urw/antiqua

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an XY-problem here.  You don’t want to install your own packages in `TEXMFDIST`, and you don’t need to download any extra files at all.

The font is in fact available in TeX Live as [the `antiqua` package.](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/urw-antiqua)  If you check the directory `c:\texlive\2020\texmf-dist\fonts\vf\urw\antiqua` or type `kpsewhich uaq.map` at the command prompt, you should see some of its files.  Otherwise, as an Administrator, run

```
tlmgr update --self --all
tlmgr install antiqua grotesq
```

There isn’t a `.sty` package provided for this font.  You would use it as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\renewcommand\rmdefault{uaq}

\begin{document}
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
\end{document}
```

[image: URW Antiqua sample]

This sets up URW Antiqua as the default Roman font.  You might want to set URW Grotesq as the matching sans-serif font, with `\renewcommand\sfdefault{ugq}`.  In TeX Live 2020, you don’t also need `textcomp` or `inputenc`, but on an older installation you might.

If you want to use this font without making it the default, you can define something like `\newcommand\URWAntiqua{\fontfamily{uaq}\selectfont}`.  And perhaps also `\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textantiqua}{\fontfamily{uaq}}`.

If you want to install the extra downloads, you can find your `TEXMFLOCAL` directory with `kpsewhich var-value=TEXMFLOCAL`.  This is probably `C:\texlive\texmf-local`.  Download the zip file and extract it to this directory, or to a new subdirectory if you want all the files in one place.  Finally, run

```
texhash
updmap-sys
```

You should now be able to compile a simple testcase with `urw.sty`.